# Problems with Tails

Tags: tails-os

I'm new here so I don't know much things about DarkNet, Operating Systems and such. I am actually trying to install [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/), but I am having problems in the cloning part. Take a look on the error.

```
Clearing unreadable partition table. Partitioning device /dev/sdc
Formatting /dev/sdc1 as FAT32 Verifying filesystem... Extracting live
image to the target device... Reading extracted MBR from
/media/amnesia/Tails/utils/mbr/mbr.bin 2 Tails installation failed!
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/media/amnesia/Tails/utils/mbr/mbr.bin'
```

I had tried to install it in many USB drives, reading the Tails website searching for something, but I found nothing. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you setting up the drive in Windows or a Linux distro? Do you need a persistent volume or are you just using it to browse?

Comment: I am setting it in Windows, and yes, I need a persistent volume.

Comment: Right, setting up a persistent volume on tails is a bit of a pain in that you need to do it *from* tails. Considering you said you've tried on multiple drives that's good because you'll need two. I'll post an answer in a little while when I get to a pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installing Tails (the easy way)**

Okay, so the easiest way to set up a Tails USB is by using a tool like [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Just download the .iso from the [Tails website](https://tails.boum.org/) and select it in the tool of your choice as well as a USB drive to install it on.

If using this method with LiLi (Rufus probably has the functionality as well) do NOT configure persistance at this point.

**Configuring a persistant volume**

You'll need a second USB drive for this. Some say it works if they boot into a Tails VM but, when I tried this, it didn't allow me to do the do and so this way is more reliable.

Boot into the Tails installation you created in the last step, insert the second USB drive and go to:

- Applications -> Tails -> Tails Installer
- Select the second USB drive
- After it installs to the second USB drive, remove the first one and it should automatically boot into the second. If not, just manually reboot into it.
- You should now be able to create a persistant volume by going to Applications -> Tails -> Configure persistent volume.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help